# ArrayList Boolean error

Tags: java, arraylist, boolean, jgrasp

I'm a noob using jGrasp. From what I have seen, the code below is correct, but I'm still getting an error. I checked my Java version, it is up to date per the Java version checker.

```
ArrayList<String> item = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Boolean> completed = new ArrayList<Boolean>();  

// Constructor 
public ToDoList(String aItem) { 
    item.add(aItem);

    // the following line give error: 
    // no suitable method found for add(boolean)
    completed.add(false);      
}
```

Comment: try with `completed.add(Boolean.FALSE)`

Comment: This should work.  Please show your entire `ToDoList` class and your Java version number.

Comment: It compiles fine for me.

Comment: I dnt thnk its will trow any error.Looks fine

Comment: Are you positive that that is the line where the error is occurring? I've never used jGrasp, is it possible that old `.class` files are still laying around somewhere (is there some way to clean and rebuild your project)?

Comment: Try to post all your stacktrace here, may be something with your imports. Who knows, may be some custom i.am.the.best.programmer.ArrayList class is used...

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. I'm glad someone confirmed this would compile. I copied the code into a new class file and in a new directory and it compiled just fine. Weird. Thanks Jason for your suggestion.